# Inverse of specified matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me in finding the general form of inverse matrix to matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns with elements except elements on diagonal, equal $1$ and elements on diagonal equal $1+x_1$, $1+x_2$, ..., $1+x_n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Your matrix can be written as
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & 0 & x_3 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}_{n \times n} + \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}_{n \times 1} \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1& 1& \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}_{1 \times n}$$
Now you can make use of the [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) i.e.
$$(X+ee^T)^{-1} = X^{-1} - \dfrac{X^{-1}ee^TX^{-1}}{1+e^TX^{-1}e}$$
I will let you compute these relevant quantities.